# Polymer 2.0 dynamically assigned id to a <ul> in dom-repeat template returns null in observe method on a array using this.shadowRoot.querySelector()

Tags: polymer-2.x, polymer-2.0, sortablejs

I am trying to implement Sortablejs in Polymer2.0 app, where in I dynamically assign ids to the ul element in a dom repeat template.

The problem I have is I can't access the ul with id in the observer method of the data list todos.

I tried document.getElementId, this.$.querySelector but both return null and Sortablejs create method throws error that html el is required. I have also tried this.shadowRoot.querySelector(child.id) ... it also returned null.

I am struggling since last 2 days to get it working. what is it that I need to do to fix it? Help pls.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<dom-module id="t-page">
<script src="http://SortableJS.github.io/Sortable/Sortable.js"> . 
</script>

<template is="dom-bind">
<style include="shared-styles">
 ....
</style>

<div class="board­__sprint">
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{todos}}" as="row">
    <div class="list">
      <div class="list­-content">
          <ul id="[[row.id]]"> 
          <!-- id is v789878 (some random unique number prefix by v per row -->
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{row.tasks}}" as="todo">
              <li>
                <div class="ticket" data-index$="{{todo.id}}">
                  <paper-card style="float:center; width: 100%;" class="singleColor" data-index$="{{todo}}"
                    data-index$="{{row}}">
                        <h7 class="banksTitle" style="color: black; font-size: 12px; text-align:left;">
                          <b>[{{index}}]</b> &nbsp; &nbsp; [[todo.actTitle]]
                        </h7>
                        <h7 class="banksTitle" style="color: grey; font-size: 12px; text-align:left;">
                          [[todo.actDesc]]
                        </h7>
                  </paper-card>
                </div>
              </li>
            </template>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="addTicket">
          <paper-button raised class="blue" on-tap="_addTicketDialog" row={{row}}>Add Ticket</paper-button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>

 <script>
  /**
   * @polymer
   * @extends HTMLElement
   */
  class TPage extends Polymer.Element {

  static get is() {
    return 't-page';
  }

  static get properties() {
    return {
      todos: {
        type: Object,
        notify: true,
        observer: '_todosChanged'
      },
   ....
   }

   _todosChanged() {
    console.log('this.todos.length = ' + this.todos.length);
    if (this.todos !== null || this.todos !== undefined) {
      var self = this;
      this.todos.forEach(function (child) {
       Sortable.create(self.$.querySelector(child.id), {
          group: 'shared'
        });
      });
    }
  }

window.customElements.define(TPage.is, TPage);
```

Comment: I am not sure if the observer method on todo list is the issue. I tried all possible combinations but always get null on the access. I tried this.$ / this.$[''] / this.$$('') / this.shadowRoot.querySelector('') after reading 1.0 and 2.0 docs on polymer... none worked. all return null. This is killing me now. I don't know how to access html elements inside dom-repeat in observer method of a property. Help pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three points in order to select your element:

> 1. [Id standards:](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least `one character`. The value must not contain any space characters...

```
 <ul id="myid[[row.id]]">
```

> 2. Rendering timing of dom-repeat. For this you may wrap your function `setTimeout` to be sure to render your all items in dom-repeat.

```
_todosChanged() {
        setTimeout(()=>{ 
            console.log('this.todos.length = ' + this.todos.length);
            if (this.todos !== null || this.todos !== undefined) {
               var self = this
              this.todos.forEach(child=> {
               console.log(child.id)
               var selector = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#myid'+child.id);
               Sortable.create(selector, {
                  group: 'shared'
                });
              });
            }
          })
}
```

> 3. The context of your function is not bound to the Polymer object, So the shortest solution is use array function ( ES6 ):

```
this.todos.forEach(child=> {....
```

instead of:

```
this.todos.forEach(function (child) {...
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/cappittall/pen/BEGgLX?editors=1011)